# Binary Search Tree find successor of given key (where the key does not have to be in tree)

Tags: search, tree, binary

How would I change the following code I have written to account for an inputed pair k that is not in the bst? In other words, how would I find the successor of a key in a binary search tree that does not exist in it?

```
public Record getSuccessor(Pair k, Node root) {

    if(root == null) {
        return null;
    }

    if(k.compareTo(root.getNodeRecord().getKey()) == 0) {
        if(root.getRightChild() != null) {
            return getSmallest(root.getRightChild());
        }
        else {
            return root.getParent().getNodeRecord();
        }
    }
    else {
        Record left = getSuccessor(k, root.getLeftChild());
        if(left != null) {
            return left;
        }
        return getSuccessor(k, root.getRightChild());
    }
}
```

Comment: could you give an example? for instance, what if the key is `2` and you have `2`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `8` in BST. which value do you imply by `successor not in bst`? by the way there is a mismatch between the title of your question (predecessor) and question itself (successor)

Comment: @mangusta for example, if the key is 5 and we have 8, 3, 1, 6, 4, 7 ,10, 14 and 3 is BST, the successor to 5 (although 5 is not in the BST) would be 6

Comment: have you tried in-order DFS traversal? it is going to give you all bst elements in increasing order so that you may find the successor of any key in linear time

Comment: ah, seems that the traversal is not necessary at all. you simply save the current node everytime before going left, and then there are several possible cases: 1. you reached the key but it doesn't have a right child. then successor is the key you saved on going left last time. 2. you reached the key and it has a right child, then you move right and then continuously move left until you reach leaf node. 3. the key is not in tree. then you end up with some leaf node and its successor is the key you saved on going left last time